# Parse between pre tag Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, pre

I'm trying to parse between PRE tags using Python using this code

```
s = br.open(base_url+str(string))
u = br.geturl()
seq = br.open(u)
blat = BeautifulSoup(seq)    
for res in blat.find('pre').findChildren():
        seq = res.string
        print seq
```

from the following HTML source code:

```
<PRE><TT>
<span style='color:#22CCEE;'>T</span><span style='color:#3300FF;'>AAAAGATGA</span> <span style='color:#3300FF;'>AGTTTCTATC</span> <span style='color:#3300FF;'>ATCCAAA</span>aa<span style='color:#3300FF;'>A</span> <span style='color:#3300FF;'>TGGGCTACAG</span> <span style='color:#3300FF;'>AAAC</span><span style='color:#22CCEE;'>C</span></TT></PRE>
<HR ALIGN="CENTER"><H4><A NAME=genomic></A>Genomic chr17 (reverse strand):</H4>
<PRE><TT>
tacatttttc tctaactgca aacataatgt tttcccttgt attttacaga  41256278
tgcaaacagc tataattttg caaaaaagga aaataactct cctgaacatc  41256228
<A NAME=1></A><span style='color:#22CCEE;'>T</span><span style='color:#3300FF;'>AAAAGATGA</span> <span style='color:#3300FF;'>AGTTTCTATC</span> <span style='color:#3300FF;'>ATCCAAA</span>gt<span style='color:#3300FF;'>A</span> <span style='color:#3300FF;'>TGGGCTACAG</span> <span style='color:#3300FF;'>AAAC</span><span style='color:#22CCEE;'>C</span>gtgcc  41256178
aaaagacttc tacagagtga acccgaaaat ccttccttgg taaaaccatt  41256128
tgttttcttc ttcttcttct tcttcttttc tttttttttt ctttt</TT></PRE>
<HR ALIGN="CENTER"><H4><A NAME=ali></A>Side by Side Alignment</H4>
<PRE><TT>
00000001 taaaagatgaagtttctatcatccaaaaaatgggctacagaaacc 00000045
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||  |||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
41256227 taaaagatgaagtttctatcatccaaagtatgggctacagaaacc 41256183

</TT></PRE>
```

It gives me the first PRE tag elements when I want to parse the last one. I'd appreciate any suggestions to achieve it. 
I'd like the output to be like:

```
00000001 taaaagatgaagtttctatcatccaaaaaatgggctacagaaacc 00000045
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||  |||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
41256227 taaaagatgaagtttctatcatccaaagtatgggctacagaaacc 41256183
```

whereas my current output is

```
T
AAAAGATGA
AGTTTCTATC
ATCCAAA
A
TGGGCTACAG
AAAC
C
```

Comment: You should use an HTML parser to parse HTML, such as (for example) [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: @DavidRobinson: I'm pretty sure he's using some HTML parser; if `blat` is just a string, rather than a tree/soup/etc. object, `blat.find('pre').findChildren()` obviously wouldn't work, because strings don't have a `findChildren` method.

Comment: But to the OP, you have to tell us which library you're actually using rather than make us guess and possibly give you a useless answer.

Comment: I've been using both BeautifulSoup and mechanize. Please find the edited code.

Comment: @user3783999: Why are you calling `findChildren`? That's an undocumented name only provided for backward compatibility with 3.x, and even in 3.x it was deprecated and not documented (and of course 3.x is itself deprecated). If you're copying and pasting source from a really ancient tutorial or something, you really shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) an get the last result:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('../index.html'), 'html5lib')

pre = soup.find_all('pre')[-1]
print pre.text.strip()
```

where `index.html` contains the html you provided.

It prints:

```
00000001 taaaagatgaagtttctatcatccaaaaaatgggctacagaaacc 00000045
<<<<<<<< ||||||||||||||||||||||||||| |||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
41256227 taaaagatgaagtttctatcatccaaagtatgggctacagaaacc 41256183
```

---

Another option would be to rely on the previous `h4` tag to get the appropriate `pre`:

```
h4 = soup.select('h4 > a[name="ali"]')[0].parent
print h4.find_next_sibling('pre').text.strip()
```

Comment: Never mind my previous comment; I thought you were replacing the `findChildren()` with `find_all()`, not the `find`. Yeah, this answer is [exactly what the documentation suggests](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names): "If you need to get *all* the `<a>` tags, or anything more complicated than the first tag with a certain name, you’ll need to use one of the methods described in Searching the tree, such as `find_all()`:"

Comment: @abarnert yeah, thanks. I'm still trying to rely on smth else instead of getting all `pre` tags..